# Java Properties Automatically Use Test Resources

Tags: java, classpath, testng

I have a few classes that need some environment specific configuration. I turned to using properties files, which are loaded in the constructor of the class.

```
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        try {
            ValidatedEnvironmentProperties props = new ValidatedEnvironmentProperties();
            props.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myclass.properties"));
```

`ValidatedEnvironmentProperties` extends `Properties`. Basically, it uses a Java System Property to set a key prefix. I set the System property to, say, `production`, and in the properties files, I have `staging.url=...` and `production.url=...`. This allows me build/runtime selection of which configuration is used while not needing to change property file name.

`myclass.properties` is stored in `src/main/resources`.

That works fine, and I rather like the how it works. My problem is that I'm sort of stuck with TestNG. I want to test a bunch of other properties in TestNG unit tests. This led me to create `src/test/resources/myclass.properties`. Instead of "environment" keys, I use test names like `bad_url_test.url=this_ain't_a_url`.

I was thinking that `src/test/resources` would get a higher priority in the classpath/classloader (terminology?), causing the test-specific properties to load. Then, for my various tests, I just set the Java System property to `bad_url_test`, instantiate `MyClass`, test my assertions, and then set the System property to a new test, instantiate a new object, and repeat.

I believe the source of the problem is this line in `MyClass`'s constructor:

```
props.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/myclass.properties"));
```

In `MyClassTest`, I put these lines to try to understand what's happening:

```
    File f = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    System.out.println("MyClass classpath: " + f.toString());
    f = new File(MyClassTest.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
    System.out.println("MyClassTest classpath: " + f.toString());
```

Output is:

```
MyClass classpath: /home/fandingo/code/project/build/classes/main
MyClassTest classpath: /home/fandingo/code/project/build/classes/test
```

MyClassTest is correct, but I need something accessible within `MyClass`'s constructor that will automatically prefer `/src/test/resources/` when running tests but `/src/main/resources/` when running normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). i.e. `MyClass` needs to be told where to get its properties from and not decide on its own.

There are lots of ways to do this but they all come down to the same idea: `MyClass` should not know at compile time where its properties come from.

e.g.

**In MyClass.java**

```
ValidatedEnvironmentProperties props = new ValidatedEnvironmentProperties();
String resourceSupplierClassName = System.getProperty("resource-supplier-class-name",
        MyClass.class.getName());
Class<?> resourceSupplierClass = Class.forName(resourceSupplierClassName);
props.load(resourceSupplierClass.getResourceAsStream("/myclass.properties"));
```

**In MyClassTest.java**

```
System.setProperty("resource-supplier-class-name", MyClassTest.class.getName());
```

Again, there are many ways to do this. Instead of passing around system properties, etc. you can also use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (a form of inversion of control). You can change the `MyClass` constructor to take your `props` as an argument and then put the onus on the instantiators of `MyClass` to provide the `props` or you can use a dependency injection framework such as [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) or [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) to manage creating the appropriate `props` instance for main/test execution and provide it to objects that need it as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I figured it had something to do with the `class` I was using with `getResourceAsStream()`. I like the System Property solution that dynamically looks up a classloader (?). I really want to stay away from passing this info around in constructors since there's several classes that use this property-loading strategy and many instantiation places. Thanks!